# Splitting up a WIX file

Tags: wix

So I thought it'd be clever of me to split my WIX file up into various smaller files.  I did this for a couple reasons.  One being that it would make it easier to maintain.  Anyway, regardless of my reason, I put the components in one file.  But when I compile, I now get a warning that says:

warning LGHT1079: The cabinet 'media1.cab' does not contain any files.  If this installation contains no files, this warning can likely be safely ignored.  Otherwise, please add files to the cabinet or remove it.

Now the Media element is in the main wix file and all of my File components have a DiskId that matches.  So I thought I'd just stick the Media element in the same fragments as where I define my components.  No dice.  I get a warning that says that the installer has no media.

So do I have to define all of my components in the same file?  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what I did wrong.  I also put the features in a separate file.  I needed to add a FeatureRef tag for each feature within the product tag.

Answer (score 1):

Your Feature elements will need ComponentRef or ComponentGroupRef elements to associate the components to the features.